# OpenGL - vertex color in shader gets swapped

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, shader, swap

I'm trying to send colors to the shader but the colors get swapped, 
I send 0xFF00FFFF (magenta) but I get 0xFFFF00FF (yellow) in the shader.

I think is happening something like this, by experimenting:

[image]

My vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec4 color;

uniform mat4 pr_matrix;
uniform mat4 vw_matrix = mat4(1.0);
uniform mat4 ml_matrix = mat4(1.0);

out DATA
{
    vec4 position;
    vec3 normal;
    vec4 color;
} vs_out;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = pr_matrix * vw_matrix * ml_matrix * position;

    vs_out.position = position;
    vs_out.color = color;
    vs_out.normal = normalize(mat3(ml_matrix) * normal);
}
```

And the fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 out_color;

in DATA
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 normal;
    vec4 color;
} fs_in;

void main()
{
    out_color = fs_in.color;

    //out_color = vec4(fs_in.color.y, 0, 0, 1);
    //out_color = vec4((fs_in.normal + 1 / 2.0), 1.0);
}
```

Here is how I set up the mesh:

```
struct Vertex_Color {
    Vec3 vertex;
    Vec3 normal;
    GLint color; // GLuint tested
};


std::vector<Vertex_Color> verts = std::vector<Vertex_Color>();

[loops]
    int color = 0xFF00FFFF; // magenta, uint tested
    verts.push_back({ vert, normal, color });


glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts.size() * sizeof(Vertex_Color), &verts[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex_Color), (const GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex_Color), (const GLvoid*)(offsetof(Vertex_Color, normal)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex_Color), (const GLvoid*)(offsetof(Vertex_Color, color)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

Here are some examples:

[image: Examples]

I can't figure it out what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is reinterpreting an `int` as 4 consecutive bytes in memory. The internal encoding for `int` (and all other types) is machine-specific. In your case, you got 32 bit integers stored in [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) byte order, which is kind of the typical case for PC environments.

You could use an array like `GLubyte color[4]` to explicitely get a defined memory layout.

If you really want to use an integer type, you could send the data as a an integer attribute with [`glVertexAttribIPointer`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) (note the I there) and use [`unpackUnorm4x8`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/unpackUnorm.xhtml) om the shader to get a normalized float vector. However, that requires at least GLSL 4.10, and might be less efficient than the standard approach.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I will use Vec4 for the colors.